# Run command as another user in Linux with `su - user c` creates a duplicate process

Tags: linux, process, debian, su

I want to run a process by a service as root user, because the daemon may have its own user.

But when I run it with `system("su - root c ./testbin")`, the system shows two processes (I check this via `ps aux | grep testbin`):

```
su - root c ./testbin
```

and

```
./testbin
```

How to achieve a single process?

Answer (score 1):

The "su" process can not be avoided, but you can get it to end before your testbin does.
Your original question using "sleep" looks like this:

```
(su - root -c "sleep 120" &) ; ps aux | grep sleep
```

If you execute that line multiple times you will see multiple "su" processes as a result of the grep.
Backgrounding the subprocess allows the su process to end, like this:

```
(su - root -c "sleep 120 &" &) ; ps aux | grep sleep
```

When you execute that line multiple times you can see that the "su" processes disappear from the list but that the sleep commands continue.

Note that the ampersand inside the double quotes is for the sub process and that the ampersand just before the parentheses is for the 'su' command which is required to perform your question in a single line and speed up testing this case.

I checked if an equivalent of 'execv' exists for the command line, but this does not seem to be the case.  Also, 'su' is a process that runs with the permissions of the caller and the subprocess of su runs with the permissions of the process forked by 'su'.  It seems logical to me that you can not replace the 'su' process with its child as 'execv' does in 'C' for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer now it listing only my testbin process only and it was actually su command process.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep testbin | grep -v grep
```

I think you just see your "grep" process. Use the command above.